# I can't get preg_match to test if the entire string matches the regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using this regular expression to test if a username is valid:

`[A-Za-z0-9 _]{3,12}` when I test it for matches in a text editor with the string `test'ing`, it highlights 'test' and 'ing', but when I use the following code in PHP:

`if(!preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9 _]{3,12}/', $content)` where $content is `test'ing` and it should return FALSE, it still returns true.

Is there something wrong with my regular expression? I need:

- Minimum length 3, max 12 `{3,12}`
- No spaces/underscores in front or after the string, and no spaces/underscores in a row anywhere
  (I'm using additional checks for this because I'm not very good with regex)
- Only alphanumerics, spaces and underscores allowed `[A-Za-z0-9 _]`

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the anchors in the regular expression, so the regex can comfortably match 3 characters in the character class *anywhere* in the string. This is not what you want. You want to check if your regex matches against the **entire string**. For that, you need to include the anchors (`^` and `$`).

```
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]{3,12}$/', $content)
                 ^                   ^
```

`^` asserts the position at the beginning of the string and `$` asserts position at the end of the string. It's important to note that these meta characters do not actually consume characters. They're zero-width assertions.

Further reading:

- [Regex Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) on [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)
- [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/1438393)

Comment: Oops, simulposted; sorry about that :(

Comment: @Piskvor: Ha, that happens. No worries. (I usually wait for the 5-minute grace period to be over before I make any edits. :)

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! Could you also help me check for spaces and underscores at the start and end of the string?

Answer (score 4):

You should add start and end anchors (`^$`):

```
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]{3,12}$/', $content)
```

The anchor `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end. That way, it will only match if the *whole* string satisfies your regex.

Hope that helps

Comment: @AmitJoki, Haha, Can't today, Already maxed out and really tired. Tomorrow maybe :)